# TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object when passing one hot encodings

Tags: python, numpy

I'm new to Tensorflow and I am trying to use it for the MNIST dataset.

My training data is a set of rows, where each row has in the first column the label and in the following columns the numeric value of the corresponding pixel in the image, like this:

```
1   220     0   0   0   0   0   0   19   0  0   0   0   251     0   0   0   0
```

I am reading the data like this:

```
train_data = pd.read_csv("../input/train.csv", delimiter=',')
train_labels = tf.one_hot(train_data.ix[:,0], 10)
train_inputs = train_data.ix[:, 1:]
```

I am trying to convert the labels into one hot encodings in order to pass them to the classifier.

The cost of the configuration is computed like this:

```
_, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: train_inputs,
                                                          y: train_labels})
```

However, on this line, I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../src/script.py", line 88, in <module>
12.5s
4
    y: train_labels})
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 789, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 948, in _run
    raise TypeError('The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. '
TypeError: The value of a feed cannot be a tf.Tensor object. Acceptable feed values include Python scalars, strings, lists, numpy ndarrays, or TensorHandles.
```

Any idea how to make this classification and cost computation work?

Comment: Did you initialized your variables ? `init = tf.global_variables_initializer()` 
`sess.run(init)`

Comment: Yes, I did run that.

Comment: Can you paste your entire code ? @octavian

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me too. Notice your variable: `train_labels`. You are using `tf.one_hot` before passing the variable to the `feed_dict`. This makes `train_labels` a tensor which is not supported.

Therefore the error:

> The value of a feed cannot be a tf